# What does the 'cd' in dhcpcd mean?

Tags: linux, dhcp, gnu

Normally, the shortened command or program names have a deeper meaning - in this case, I'm curious as to what the **cd** part of `dhcpcd` means (I understand what DHCP is).

I'm asking because my Google searches returned nothing on the topic.

Comment: Downvoters please explain so I can improve my questions in the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DHCP Client Daemon.

Ref: https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcpcd.8.html

This is used by a client sending DHCP request, and then daemon-ized the process - waiting for the lease time to expire, and repeat the process.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. I thought it might be something obvious :/